# Round time stamp to every 3 min in a dataframe

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with a list of time stamps:

```
|     |      Time        |
|-----|------------------|
|9677 |   02:00:37+00:00 |
|9678 |   02:00:37+00:00 |
|9679 |   02:01:32+00:00 |
|9683 |   02:02:49+00:00 |
|9684 |   02:03:51+00:00 | 
|9685 |   02:03:54+00:00 |
|9686 |   02:04:57+00:00 |
|9687 |   02:04:43+00:00 |
|9710 |   02:05:57+00:00 |
|9711 |   02:06:47+00:00 |
|9712 |   02:08:44+00:00 |
|9713 |   02:09:42+00:00 |
|9714 |   02:10:39+00:00 |
```

I want to create a column with rounding to nearest 3 min
eg:

```
|     |      Time        |    3 Min Interval  |
|-----|------------------|--------------------|
|9677 |   02:00:37+00:00 |        02:03       |
|9678 |   02:01:34+00:00 |        02:03       |
|9679 |   02:01:32+00:00 |        02:03       |
|9683 |   02:02:49+00:00 |        02:03       |
|9684 |   02:03:51+00:00 |        02:06       |
|9685 |   02:03:54+00:00 |        02:06       |
|9686 |   02:04:57+00:00 |        02:06       |
|9687 |   02:04:43+00:00 |        02:06       |
|9710 |   02:05:57+00:00 |        02:06       |
|9711 |   02:06:47+00:00 |        02:09       |
|9712 |   02:08:44+00:00 |        02:09       |
|9713 |   02:09:42+00:00 |        02:09       |
|9714 |   02:10:39+00:00 |        02:12       |
```

Ive tried grouping it per min but i want to group it per 3 min

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.dt.round`:

```
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df["Time"].dt.round("180s")
```

Output:

```
9677   2021-08-06 02:00:00+00:00
9678   2021-08-06 02:00:00+00:00
9679   2021-08-06 02:03:00+00:00
9683   2021-08-06 02:03:00+00:00
9684   2021-08-06 02:03:00+00:00
9685   2021-08-06 02:03:00+00:00
9686   2021-08-06 02:06:00+00:00
9687   2021-08-06 02:06:00+00:00
9710   2021-08-06 02:06:00+00:00
9711   2021-08-06 02:06:00+00:00
9712   2021-08-06 02:09:00+00:00
9713   2021-08-06 02:09:00+00:00
9714   2021-08-06 02:12:00+00:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

You can then use `pandas.Series.dt.strftime` to format:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).dt.round("180s")
df["3 Min Interval"] = s.dt.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Final Output:

```
                Time 3 Min Interval
9677  02:00:37+00:00          02:00
9678  02:00:37+00:00          02:00
9679  02:01:32+00:00          02:03
9683  02:02:49+00:00          02:03
9684  02:03:51+00:00          02:03
9685  02:03:54+00:00          02:03
9686  02:04:57+00:00          02:06
9687  02:04:43+00:00          02:06
9710  02:05:57+00:00          02:06
9711  02:06:47+00:00          02:06
9712  02:08:44+00:00          02:09
9713  02:09:42+00:00          02:09
9714  02:10:39+00:00          02:12
```

Comment: Nice solution @Chris, you can add .dt.strftime('%H-%M') to match output